# C++ SIGTRAP debugger issue

Tags: c++, debugging

I have one problem with my server, while it's running on debugger.

I recieve SIGTRAP message when it call delete [] pointer.

> Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. In
> ntdll!DbgUiConnectToDbg () (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll)
>
> ## 10 0x00402247 in CharacterCreateHandler::run (this=0x3e8170) at F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\handler\CharacterCreateHandler.cpp:44
>
> F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\handler\CharacterCreateHandler.cpp:44:1211:beg:0x402247
> At
> F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\handler\CharacterCreateHandler.cpp:44

Here is function where it occurs :

```
void CharacterCreateHandler::run()
{
    try
    {
        unsigned short lenWOH = _packet[0] - 8;
        Decryptor dec;
        _packet = dec.decrypt(_packet + 8, lenWOH);

        std::string characterName(_packet, 16);

        Application & app = Application::instance();

        app.logger().information(characterName);

        unsigned short len = 20;
        char * reply = new char[len]();
        ///build packet header
        //set len (it's short)
        reply[0] = len & 0xff;
        reply[1] = (len >> 8) & 0xff;
        reply[4] = 3; //group
        reply[6] = 6; //type
        ///body - static
        reply[8] = 1; //indicator
        reply[9] = 1; //indicator 
        reply[10] = 0x12; 
        reply[11] = 0x2b;
        reply[13] = 0xc0; 
        reply[14] = 0xb7; 
        reply[15] = 0xc4; 
        reply[17] = 0xe0; 
        reply[18] = 0x21;
        reply[19] = 0x45; 
        _con->sendBlocking(reply, len);
        delete [] _packet; //line 44
        delete [] reply;
        delete this;
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the class form where pointer is given (_pBuffer):

```
class CSConnection
{
    public:
        CSConnection(StreamSocket& socket, SocketReactor& reactor);

        ~CSConnection();

        void sendBlocking(char * buffer, unsigned short len);

        void sendNonblocking(char * buffer, unsigned short len);

        void onReadable(const AutoPtr<ReadableNotification>& pNf);

        void onSocketTimeout(const AutoPtr<TimeoutNotification>& pNf);

        void onShutdown(const AutoPtr<ShutdownNotification>& pNf);

        void onError(const AutoPtr<ErrorNotification>& pNf);

    private:
        enum
        {
            BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        };

        StreamSocket   _socket;
        SocketReactor& _reactor;
        char*          _pBuffer;
};
```

And function what recieve packet (_pBuffer)

```
    void CSConnection::onReadable(const AutoPtr<ReadableNotification>& pNf)
    {
        try
        {
    
            int n = _socket.receiveBytes(_pBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (n > 0)
            {
                //app.logger().information("Packet s " + nb.format(nBytes) + ", group : " + nb.format(_pBuffer[4]) + ", type : " + nb.format(_pBuffer[6]));
                unsigned short packetID;
                packetID = (_pBuffer[4] * 666) + _pBuffer[6];
                switch(packetID)
                {
                    case 666:
                        WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(*new QuitHandler(this));
                        break;
                    case 672:
                        WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(*new CharacterCreateHandler(this, _pBuffer));
                        break;
...
```

Comment: How and where do you allocate (or otherwise initialize) `_packet`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg _packet is a _pBuffer allocated by : CharacterCreateHandler(CSConnection * con, char * packet): _con(con), _packet(packet)

Comment: Then where does `packet` come from?

Comment: @MatsPetersson packet is  from CSConnection (it's _pBuffer).